# HTML how to add an input tag to an ordered list using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to add blank input fields to an ordered list (with id = myList) when the user clicks a button. I have written the following code to add a list element to the ordered list, then insert an input field in that new list element. When I execute this code, nothing happens when I hit the button.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function addToList()
     {
        var doc = document.getElementById("myList");
        var newLI = document.createElement("li");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.size = "60";
        newLi.appendChild(input);
        doc.appendChild(newLI);
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this. The problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Can you add the html part here http://jsfiddle.net/NugL2/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: If I replace this code with something simple like alert("hello world"); the function works fine when the button is clicked so I am not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo, it's `newLI`, not `newLi`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function addToList()
     {
        var doc = document.getElementById("myList");
        var newLI = document.createElement("li");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.size = "60";
        newLI.appendChild(input); // typo here, it's not newLi
        doc.appendChild(newLI);
     }
 </script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D3uay/)

Comment: Thank you! I feel so stupid. I must have looked over the code 20 times checking for a typo and didn't see it.

Comment: @user3108789 - next time open the browser console (F12) and you'll spot the error right away.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option for me because I am using Python to generate and launch the HTML and javascript code. This makes finding simple typos difficult because I don't have an editor that can point them out.